# Sending HTML string via POST to PHP. Get weird characters when ECHOing it out

Tags: php, html, post, encoding, echo

So I am making a simple script where I send a HTML string via POST to PHP and when I try to echo it out it gets encoded with some weird characters

The string Im sending:

```
'Yo <i>whats up</i>'
```

What I get when I echo it out with PHP

```
Yo+%3Ci%3Ewhats+up%3C%2Fi%3E
```

What is going on here? Is there some PHP method I can use to revert it back to the original HTML string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use

```
echo htmlspecialchars(urldecode('Yo+%3Ci%3Ewhats+up%3C%2Fi%3E'));
```

The reason is that your data gets [x-www-form-urlencoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) for posting. So on the server-side, you have to decode it again - that's what [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) does.

[htmlspecialchars()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) prevents your HTML-Tags to be rendered as such so they are just displayed as a string (if that's what you want).

So, in an HTML context, `echo urldecode('Yo+%3Ci%3Ewhats+up%3C%2Fi%3E');` would output

> Yo *whats up*

And if you also wrap it with htmlspecialchars(), your output would be

> `Yo <i>whats up</i>`

again.

Comment: Switching the forms enctype to "text/plain" instead of the default "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" would be better than using `urldecode`.

Comment: Actually Pedro after reading a little more on it, it turns out if i use "text/plain" the empty spaces still get converted to "+" signs. For data to be completely unencrypted it has to be "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your post string is being encoded for url.

you can use urldecode to remove these characters

```
echo urldecode($_POST['string']);
```